# callback for add-to-timeline plugin?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

When a user comes to my website and tries to allow publish_action permission, he will click on the '[add-to-timeline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/)' plugin button.
Then a popup dialog appears and user will allow the required permission.
What I want to find out is that if we can specify any callback function to invoke after user allows the permission.

I know we can subscribe to 'edge.create' event through FB.Event.subscribe, but I couldn't find a similar solution for 'add-to-timeline'.
At least, it wasn't written on its document as far as I read.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to the [global events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to accomplish this.

If you subscribe to **auth.login**, **auth.authResponseChange**, or **auth.statusChange** they will be called after the user authorized your application via '[add-to-timeline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/)'.

So for example you could do this...

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  alert('The user has just authorized your application');
});
```

However I'm guessing what you want is the same thing that I wanted which is to have the action added to the timeline after the user clicks 'add-to-timeline' the first time and then on subsequent visits to your site just have it added to the timeline automatically.

To do that you would do this...

```
/** put your FB.init right here **/

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    FB.api("/me/foobar:watch" + "?video=http://foobar.com/video/123","post",
      function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
          alert("Error");
        } else {
          alert("Post was successful! Action ID: " + response.id);
        }
      });
  }  
});
```